# Is it possible to insert values in column using just a primary key reference?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'users' with the columns:

```
user_id(PK), user_firstname, user_lastname
```

and another table 'room' with the columns:

```
event_id(PK), user_id(FK), user_firstname, user_lastname....(and more columns).
```

I want to know if it is possible to fill the `user_firstname` and `user_lastname` automatically just knowing the `user_id` column.

Like the default value of `user_firstname` would be like: "select users.user_firstname where users.user_id = user_id"

I don't know if was clear enough...As you can see my knowledge in database is very narrow.

Comment: Why do you store `user_firstname` and `user_lastname` in `room` if you have FK `user_id`?

Comment: Because I wanted to output a query like: SELECT * FROM room; And encode this into a JSON using PHP, so I could access the user_firstname and user_lastname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done with `JOIN`s. They will avoid those redundant `user_firstname` and `user_lastname` columns. So you'd just fetch from both tables when querying the room table and you get the extra columns of `users` into the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM room AS r INNER JOIN users AS u ON r.user_id = u.user_id;
```

The thing we did here is called **normalization**. Another important thing to take care of are **foreign key constraints** and their **cascades**, in your case `room.user_id references user.user_id`. A `delete` on `user` should most probably cascade to `room`, if you want to delete users, instead of flagging them deleted.

Comment: Hmm I see.. thank you all for the answer! I think I got it now :D

Answer (score 4):

The columns user_firstname and user_lastname do not belong in your room table.  The user_id column references the users table, that is all you need.
To select the data, you can use a JOIN statement, something like

```
SELECT R.event_id, R.user_id, U.user_firstname, U.user_lastname
FROM room AS R
JOIN users AS U ON R.user_uid = U.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is sideways to the question. You *do not* want a `user_firstname` and `user_lastname` column in the Event table. The `user_id` is a proxy for that row of the entire User table. When you need to access `user_firstname`, you do a **JOIN** of the two tables on the common column.